# find unique rows in MATLAB while the column are of different datatype

Tags: matlab

```
'<s>'           15
'an'            3
'evolutionary'  2
'immune'        4
'network'           4
'for'           4
'data'          2
'clustering'    2
'</s>'         15
'<s>'          15
'an'            3
'evolutionary'  2
'immune'            4
'network'           4
'for'           4
'data'          2
'clustering'    2
'</s>'          15
'<s>'            15
```

I am working in *MATLAB*, the question is how i can find out the unique rows while the data type of each column is different. The table which is given above have first column of **char** data type while the second column of **double** type?

Comment: Matlab's `unique` has a `'rows'` flag. Have you tried it?: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#btb0_85

Comment: I understand some people learn better from tutors than from books, documentation, etc., so I have no problems with you asking questions like this. However, as a good tutor, I should be teaching you *problem-solving techniques*, rather than how to tackle individual problems. For this particular problem, the topmost Google results from the query "matlab unique rows" are pretty well-written and should more than answer your question...

Comment: Stack Overflow is more intended to solve problems that are not a few  Google queries away. SO (and by extension, SE) is very good for finding experts from very specific disciplines, so that they can have a look at your problem. Naturally, as you may understand, these experts *do* expect you to have "done your homework" :)

Comment: @Dan yes i have read that one but for different type of data is was giving error but i solved this problem in another way.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis yes i am agree with you, as i am new to MATLAB so first i try to solve the problem by myself but sometimes i got large number lines of code that's why i asked this question.

Comment: @user2753079 if you're worried that your code is inefficient you should post it as part of your question next time, people will be far more inclined to help you here if you show first what you have tired. Also if you have now solved your issue, I would encourage you to post is as an answer to your own question for others to see in the future. Also that way, if there is a better way someone might point it out.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution for the above code is:

I/P-Test

```
'<s>'   'hi'    'hello' '</s>'  '<s>'   
6   5   1   6   6
```

O/P-Test1

```
'<s>'   'hi'    'hello' '</s>'
   6    5   1   6   



j=1;
Test1(:,j) = Test(:,1);
j=j+1;
for i=2:size(Test,2)
    if(isempty(strmatch(Test(1,i),Test1(1:1,:),'exact')))
        Test1(:,j) = Test(:,i);
        j=j+1;
    end
end
```